# Git on TFS hangs on push

Tags: git, tfs

I have the following issue: Try to push a single commit to a TFS Git repositiry with 70KiB size and it always hangs. I have to cancel.
If I push a smaller commit everything is up to normal. This happens only in my environment.

Comment: did you ever solved your issue ?

Comment: Yes. I started to use the git client from Atlasian instead of the original Git for Windows.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git push hangs on POST git-receive-pack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799527/git-push-hangs-on-post-git-receive-pack)