# Git push hangs on POST git-receive-pack

Tags: image, git, tfs, git-push

I'm on a Windows 8 Machine with git version 1.9.5.msysgit.0 pushing to a TFS Git Repository hosted on HTTPS.

When I push any text file everything is fine. But pushing a certain .jpg file git hangs on POST git-recieve-pack with the following output:

```
$ git push -v
Pushing to https://tfs.ourcompanyn.com/tfs/DefaultCollection/Prototypes/_git/TestProject
Counting objects: 11, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Writing objects: 100% (5/5), 59.76 KiB | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 5 (delta 3), reused 0 (delta 0)
POST git-receive-pack (61329 bytes)
```

It stays like this and does not change anymore

We use wincred as credentialhelper and I've checked that authentication works. Also I can push code. Just some of the .jpeg Files create this problem.

Is CMYK / RGB a problem? Is https with git and tfs a problem?

EDIT:
I've tried so far to increase http.postbuffer as mentioned [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10790232/hanging-at-post-git-receive-pack-chunked).

```
git config http.postBuffer 524288000
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The problem occurs with msysgit and curl in the current version. There's a problem with handling authentication over HTTPS:

Documented here:
https://github.com/msysgit/git/issues/349

Solution:
Install the pre-release of [Git for Windows 2.x](https://git-for-windows.github.io/index.html)

**UPDATE:**

Version 2.5.1 for Windows is released, so please use that one.
https://git-scm.com/download/win

Comment: This worked for me, even though the remote was HTTP rather than HTTPS.  Thanks!

Comment: Shoot... I have spent hours for this thinking my on-premise GIT server was defective. I had been searching for alternative servers. After reading this, I checked my GIT version and it was 1.9.5 or something. I updated to the latest version and now the problem seems to be solved.