# Git Push doesn't finish

Tags: git

After running git push, it doesn't return bash prompt. I have to hit `ctrl+c` to get the prompt. I'm not sure if  hitting `ctrl+c` might cause any issue to the push?

Tested it using latest git version 2.24.1 and problem persist.

This started happening after I ran the command `git config http.postBuffer 524288000` since the push was very slow (at 11 Kib/s) when the file count was greater than 1024. Now the push is fast but doesn't return back to shell.

```
Counting objects: 1703, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1649/1649), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1702/1702), 176.35 MiB | 4.97 MiB/s, done.
Total 1702 (delta 517), reused 0 (delta 0)
Its' stuck here.. Doesn't return bash prmopt.
```

In Verbose mode it is stuck at `POST`

```
Counting objects: 1703, done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1649/1649), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1702/1702), 176.35 MiB | 4.88 MiB/s, done.
Total 1702 (delta 516), reused 0 (delta 0)
POST git-receive-pack (184921569 bytes)
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Git push hangs on POST git-receive-pack](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799527/git-push-hangs-on-post-git-receive-pack)

Comment: What version of GIT are you using?

Comment: @DaemonPainter given that the answer to that was "update GIT" and given that that question was answered in 2015 it seems VERY unlikely that the OP is using a 2015 version of GIT. At the very least it would make sense to check what version the OP is using before voting to close this as a dupe.

Comment: Same issue with the latest version. Just updated it to `git version 2.24.1`

Comment: @Liam on the other hand, since it is known that git version could lead to this issue, the question is either to be flagged as "missing debugging information" (i reckon) or "duplicated" for traceability. This would make a fine discussion on meta.

Comment: Can you test with the actual latest Git? (2.30)

Comment: okay I'll try it on 2.30

Comment: centos 7 doesn't seem to have git 2.30

Comment: Consider that your `git push` might still be running at just 11 kiB/s. If so, sending 185 MiB will take about 1681 seconds or roughly 28 minutes.