# Git push stuck after git gc

Tags: git, github, push

I have a problem with git. I tried several solutions found online but nothing works.

I first met an error :

```
error: RPC failed; curl 55 OpenSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 10053
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I tried a git gc

After that I did a git push. At the end, nothing happend and gets stuck.

I assume that a lots of posts here are similar, but I don"t want to lose all my work :/

```
git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Enumerating objects: 259, done.
Counting objects: 100% (259/259), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (137/137), done.
Writing objects: 100% (178/178), 327.92 MiB | 6.99 MiB/s, done.
Total 178 (delta 101), reused 90 (delta 35), pack-reused 0
```

I did a git push -v but it stops there :

```
git: 'credential-manager' is not a git command. See 'git --help'.
Enumerating objects: 259, done.
Counting objects: 100% (259/259), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (137/137), done.
Writing objects: 100% (178/178), 327.92 MiB | 6.84 MiB/s, done.
Total 178 (delta 101), reused 90 (delta 35), pack-reused 0
POST git-receive-pack (343847271 bytes)
```

UPDATE

Sometimes, after a while I receive that error :

```
error: RPC failed; curl 56 LibreSSL SSL_read: SSL_ERROR_SYSCALL, errno 54
send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
```

I already read some stuff about that error, but still don't understand what to do with it

Comment: Could https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30799527/git-push-hangs-on-post-git-receive-pack be relevant? Would be good to add some details about your git server to your post.

Comment: sorry, I don't think it is. I'm not on windows. I don't really know what else to add

Answer (score 0):

I've deal with this sort of flakiness before. If you can, by far the easiest solution seems to use SSH instead of HTTPS.

In your case you probably want to find the SSH address and [update the remote origin address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11200237/how-do-i-get-git-to-default-to-ssh-and-not-https-for-new-repositories).